# Running an event only once using the "Blink without delay" method in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, delay, milliseconds, arduino-c++

I have an Arduino sketch that controls two different motors, a stepper motor, and a DC motor, using the Adafruit motor shield library. The main function of the sketch is to accept a string parameter on the serial input formatted as: (int *motorId*, int *motorDirection*, int *motorSpeed*, int *degrees*, int *holdingTorque*) and parse it into various parameters that control the behavior of the motor.

With the DC motor, I'd like it to run for a certain interval of time before it shuts off, which would translate into a specific amount of degrees moved. I am using the *millis()* function to check when the motor should be shut off without blocking further serial input. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to execute the command to shut off the motor only once, the if statement which checks if the delta in time is greater than the *runinterval* repeatedly keeps calling the function *RAMOTOR->fullOff()* every *runinterval*.

Iv'e tried using a boolean variable with an if/while wrapper around *if (currentMillis - previousMillis > runinterval)* to make this happen only once, however, the problem with that method is that if the variable is **false** then previousMillis never gets set to currentMillis.

Here is the entirety of my main loop:

```
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    //Read char array input from serial monitor
    String input = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    /*Pass the string to the class member "ParseInput" of the parsemotorparameters object, which will
      retrieve the motor behavior parameters such as speed and steps to move and return a true boolean which sets the motor run state variable*/
    parsemotorparameters.ParseInput(input);
    //Set the runtime in seconds for the RA motor
    runinterval = parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorRuntime(DEG_PER_SEC);
    /*If motor ID returned from "ParseInput" is 1, then run the RA motor for calculated period of time that translates to
      degrees moved*/
    if (parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorId() == 1) {
      Serial.println(runinterval);
      //RAMOTOR->setSpeed(RASpeed);
      //RAMOTOR->run(parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorDirection());
      CheckRAStatus = true;
    }
    else {
      //If the holding torque boolean variable is true, then apply power to the stepper motor continously even if the motor is not activley stepping
      if (parsemotorparameters.ReturnHoldingTorque()) {
        //Set the stepper motor speed
        //DECMOTOR->setSpeed(parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorSpeed());
        /*Adafruit stepper motor class member accepts the following parameters
          step(uint8_t #steps, uint8_t direction 1 or 0, uint8_t step mode) */
        //DECMOTOR->step(parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorSteps(), parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorDirection(), MICROSTEP);
      }
      //If the holding torque boolean variable is false, then remove power from the stepper motor as soon as it's done moving
      else {
        //DECMOTOR->setSpeed(parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorSpeed());
        //DECMOTOR->step(parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorSteps(), parsemotorparameters.ReturnMotorDirection(), MICROSTEP);
        //DECMOTOR->release();
      }
    }
    debug();
  }
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis > runinterval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    //RAMOTOR->fullOff();
    Serial.println("OFF");
    CheckRAStatus = false;
  }
```

Comment: Please avoid using the phrase "C/C++". There's no such language, only the distinct and very different C and C++ languages. Arduino is typically programmed in C++, and the code you show is C++, so please [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. You do need some boolean flag

```
bool raMotorOn = false;
```

Then you set it to true around `RAMOTOR->run()` call and modify your `if`

```
if (raMotorOn && (currentMillis - previousMillis > runinterval)) {
  raMotorOn = false;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem statement and the code correctly, but you can use `CheckRAStatus` as a flag to guard against repetitive calling of `fullOff()`.

```
if (CheckRAStatus && currentMillis - previousMillis > runinterval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    RAMOTOR->fullOff();
    Serial.println("OFF");
    CheckRAStatus = false;
}
```